# Jquery functional programming style

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more elegant way to write this kind of function without having to initialize an array:

```
function getStuff () {
    var some_array= [];

    $("#some-id ul li span.key").each(function() {
          some_array.push($(this).text());
    });

    return some_array;
}
```

Comment: Isn't defining the type of variable is more clear and elegant? Why do you think it is not elegant?

Comment: this is not functional style, as you change variable

Comment: You may want to consider not writing such a function in the first place - it's not the jQuery way of doing things.

Comment: @reinierpost then what's the jquery way? please feel free to add an answer

Comment: In jQuery you write map operations on DOM elements, specified by taking a DOM selector as the argument. So you'd write a function to do whatever you intend to do with one of the elements in some_array and then wrap it such that it can be applied to a DOM selector that selects the suitable elements.

Comment: yeah that was the point of my question exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
function getStuff () {
    return $.map($("#some-id ul li span.key"), function(el) {
          return $(el).text();
    });
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/295Ch/)

[Performance](http://jsperf.com/jquerymapvseachpush/3)-wise, the difference is minimal. Also, as noted by Lix, choose the method which you find more readable and maintainable. In the end, both will end up creating an array, iterating over elements, pushing string values to the array and returning the array.

Comment: Although this does eliminate the need to initialize the array, I would not say that this is more "elegant". Readability is not as good as the original code IMO... Have a +1 in anycase :P

Comment: @Lix depends if you are used to it or not, we do lot of functional programming already

Comment: @dan - did you take a look at the demo? It is indeed an array.

Comment: @DanLee The return value of [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is an array. Oh Kevin beat me to it. `=]`

Comment: @Lix - I hear your first argument a lot and I think it's completely wrong and, generally, repeated by folks who just aren't used to the functional style and functions like reduce/map/filter. Once you are used to `map`, the above code is entirely, completely, immediately clear. Of course anything you're not used to reading is harder to read. It couldn't be more obvious to someone who writes code like that all the time.

Comment: @Lix, has a point. I'll add a paragraph about it to the answer. But @lwburk is right, once you're used to methods such as `$.map`, my piece of code is crystal-clear.

Comment: @lwb - I suppose that maintaining a consistent coding style would trump readability in this case; However one can never make assumptions about another programmers thought patterns. This code screams to me in need of a comment and I usually find when code *demands* a comment, there is usually a better, more readable way to formulate the solution. You **do** make a valid point though.

Comment: @fab - A quote from the doc's description of the `map` function is really all I think is needed here. Especially on [so] where not everyone is familiar with these (more advanced? lesser used?) methodologies. In your code I'm sure you wouldn't need it - here however, I think it's a must.

Comment: Or: `return $(...).map(...).get();`... and btw, your performance test is incorrect because you use different selectors. Here is an updated one: http://jsperf.com/jquerymapvseachpush/2.

Comment: @FelixKling I was thinking about `return $(...).map(...).toArray();` but that adds one extra function call as `.get()` does. Will add those to my jsperf to check if it provides any change.

Comment: @fel - You would still need to iterate over the array from `get()` to extract a specific attr/prop no? Eg the `.text()` of all matched elements.

Comment: @fel - As you can see from the comments above, the `map` function is not something I use regularly :P I see what you are saying now... `return $("img").map(function(){ return $(this).attr('src'); }).get();`

Comment: Not sure if I was running the initial tests wrong, now both give me very close results in Chrome and FF. @FelixKling Your revision 2 of the jsperf used a selector that didn't match any element, fixed that on my rev3. `=]` Also, weirdly enough, FF and Chrome's native `.map()` are slower than `$.map`.. Guess it's the time to call a day from benchmarking.

Comment: Oh the native `.map()` had a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: @DanLee a handful of people replied that [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) returns an array, but I guess no one mentioned that jQuery's `.map()` method can be used to iterate not only arrays, but objects too. Your comment wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 5):

Just another more functional feeling way to go about this might be:

Define a "method" function:

```
var method = function (method) {
    return function (item) {
        return $(item)[method]();
    };
};
```

You can use it like this:

```
var text = method('text');
var html = method('html');
var fadeIn = method('fadeIn');
```

To re-work your `getStuff` function:

```
var getText = function (arr) {
    return $.map(arr, text);
};
```

`$.map` iterates through the array that was passed in, applying the function that was returned from `var text = method('text')`, which is just the execution of `$(array item).method()`.

I just threw this together to demonstrate a way you can use these kinds of techniques. You would probably name things differently and define the "method" function as a custom library/helper that is meant to be used app-wide.